# How to build a dynamic URL in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am trying to send one URL which I will generate on basis of some dynamic value. But I don't want to hard code it nor want to use response or request object.

Example:

> *http://localhost:8585/app/image/{id}/{publicUrl}/{filename}*

So I want to get the first part (i.e. http://localhost:8585/app/image)
from Spring Framework only. I will provide rest of the things like `id`, `publicUrl`, `filename`, so that it can generate a complete *absolute* URL.

How to do it in Spring MVC?

Answer (score 28):

Are you trying to listen on a URL or trying to build a URL to use externally?

If the latter, you can use the [URIComponentsBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html) to build dynamic URLs in Spring. Example:

```
UriComponents uri = UriComponentsBuilder
                    .fromHttpUrl("http://localhost:8585/app/image/{id}/{publicUrl}/{filename}")
                    .buildAndExpand("someId", "somePublicUrl", "someFilename");

String urlString = uri.toUriString();
```

Comment: No my problem is that I don't want to hard code "http://localhost:8585/app/" this part. Now I am running my application in local so its showing "http://localhost:8585/" and app is the application name. What if I have uploaded this application to say www.example.com and I want to access this by using example.com . So I want to provide "/image/{id}/{publicUrl}/{filename}" part and rest will be taken care of by spring.

Answer (score 8):

Just an addition to Neil McGuigan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30525470/4293320) but without hardcoding schema, domain, port &, etc...

One could do this:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;
...
ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest
        .queryParam("page", 1)
        .toUriString();
```

imagine original request was to

```
https://myapp.mydomain.com/api/resources
```

this code will produce the following URL

```
https://myapp.mydomain.com/api/resources?page=1
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates

Have a look on that one.
"URI Template Patterns".